# Output Current Derating for Buck converter for powering RF sampling data converters

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, dac

I am new to the use of DC-DC converters.

I am designing power supply for powering DAC from TI whose part number is [DAC38RF80](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac38rf80.pdf).

DAC38RF80 is  high speed RF sampling DAC with sampling rate as high as 9 GSPS and it supports JESD204B.

There will be three DAC38RF80 on the single PCB.

There are four voltage levels required to power-up this DAC and these are:

•   1v Digital

•   1v Analog

•   1.8v

•   -1.8v

Now the current consumption for all the four voltage rails varies with the different operating modes given in the datasheet.

Maximum current consumption of 1v Digital supply is 2.29A for 1No. of DAC. So for three DAC38RF80 current consumption for 1v Digital supply is 6.87A.
[image]

I am planning to power 1v digital supply of all three DACs from single buck converter.

I have chosen TI's [TPSM84824](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpsm84824.pdf) power module which has maximum output current rating of 8A.

So my question is :

1. Will TPSM84824 module with 8A of output current be able to power up all three DAC's 1v @ 6.87A digital supply without any issue or will there be any issue like shut down of regulator due to exceeding the max current limit of regulator because of inrush at start-up?

How much derating of the current needs to be done while selecting DC-DC converter?

Also it will be very helpful to know what parameters does experienced EEs look for in datasheet of DC-DC converter for powering high speed RF sampling converters, so that performance of data converters can be improved?

Thanks.

Comment: Give an RF DAC likely has ZERO ability to reject power supply trash, particularly at the Carrier frequency where device (transistor) junction capacitances dominate the Zout, you need to plan on extensive VDD filtering, to the100microVolt or 10microVolt PP level. Expect to use RC + RC + RC low pass filters in each of your 4 power rails.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf - I am planning to use feedthrough capacitor at output of regulator as filter

Comment: @analogsystemsrf just gave you some wise advice.  A single feedthrough capacitor is not equivalent to what he suggested.

Comment: If you're happy with the specs of the DC/DC converter at the max load you shouldn't have to worry about derating. Things I would check on the DC/DC specs: max ripple, switching frequency (make sure the harmonics don't represent potential RF problems), load regulation (this may cause activity in one of the DACs to couple back to the other two), input voltage regulation (important if the input voltage is not that clean), step response (important if you're planning on dynamically shutting down / bringing up any load). And as @analogsustemsrf pointed out, you'll need to do a good job in filtering.

Comment: ... I almost forgot one of the most important things: pay lots of attention on the layout of the DC/DC converter input capacitors. They need to be very close to the module pins otherwise you'll spill switching noise all over your board (currents on these traces carry huge di/dt). I also recommend adding a series inductor or ferrite bead between the external input voltage and the input caps to prevent the switching noise from propagating upstream.

Comment: @joribama I have read somewhere that if ferrite bead is not selected carefully, then it can create more problem due to ringing and oscillations. So can you suggest me some value of ferrite bead? Like should I choose ferrite bead with impedance of  1k @ 100 MHz or 100 Ohm @ 100Mhz

Comment: Ferrite beads can cause more harm than good when placed right before a load with pulsed current characteristics, like digital loads for instance. In this case the changes in currents will get translated into changes in voltage, what ruins the voltage regulation. This is not the case for the input of a DC/DC converter. The impedance @100MHz doesn’t need to be too high for it to be effective. It’s going to be a trade off between impedance and ESR/max current. Also look at the impedance curve over frequency to make sure it will be effective for the harmonics of the switching frequency.